# Open() system call for directories and accessing files in sub-directories

Tags: c, directory, system-calls, opendir

I'm trying to open a directory and access all it's files and sub-directories and also the sub-directories files and so on(recursion).
I know i can access the files and the sub-directories by using the opendir call, but i was wondering if there is a way to do so by using the open() system call(and how?), or does the open system call only refers to files?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <dirent.h> 

int main(void) 
{ 
 struct dirent *de;  // Pointer for directory entry 

// opendir() returns a pointer of DIR type.  
DIR *dr = opendir("."); 

if (dr == NULL)  // opendir returns NULL if couldn't open directory 
{ 
    printf("Could not open current directory" ); 
    return 0; 
} 


while ((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL) 
        printf("%s\n", de->d_name); 

closedir(dr);     
return 0; 
 }
```

the following code gives me the names of the files in my directory and the names of the sub-folders, but how can I differ a file from a sub-folder so i can use recursion to access the files in the sub-folder?

any help would be appreciated

Comment: While [`readdir`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readdir.html) and the `dirent` structure is specified in POSIX, the contents of the `dirent` structure (defined in [the `<dirent.h>` header file](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/dirent.h.html)) is usually extended by implementations and actual operating systems. Some operating systems includes information like file type (regular file, pipe, *directory* etc.). But you don't tell us your OS so we can't point you further, other than telling you to read the manual page (`man readdir`).

Comment: @ Some programmer dude sorry,you're right, I'm using cloud9 for this and if I got it right the operating system is Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Then [this Linux manual page for `readdir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) should be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to have the struct stat and the macro S_ISDIR from the , if you want to check if it is a file you can use the same method but with the macro S_ISREG.
Also when you use structures is better to allocate memory before using them.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <dirent.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(void) 
{ 
 struct dirent *de = malloc(sizeof(struct dirent));  // Pointer for directory entry 
 struct stat *info; = malloc(sizeof(struct stat));

// opendir() returns a pointer of DIR type.  
DIR *dr = opendir("."); 

if (dr == NULL)  // opendir returns NULL if couldn't open directory 
{ 
    printf("Could not open current directory" ); 
    return 0; 
} 


while ((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL) 
 {
   if((S_ISDIR(info->st_mode)
    printf("Directory:%s \n", de->d_name); 
   else printf("File:"%s \n,de->d_name);
 }
closedir(dr);     
return 0; 
}
```